# How to distinguish between mouseDragged and mousePressed?

Tags: java, mouse, awt, mouselistener

I want my program to behave diffrently when the user presses a component, and when a user drags the mouse over a component, the problem is that on mouse click both of these methods are being called (and it seems like mouseDragged is called after mousePressed), so how will i know if the user dragged his mouse or just pressed it?

Comment: mouseDragged shouldn't be called on a mouse click, however java's sometimes very sensitive, so even if you move a few pixels while clicking, it ends up being a drag.

Comment: it is a fact that it does, im pretty sure i did not drag a pixel... maybe you should try it yourself

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is to use mouseClicked instead of combination of mousePressed+mouseReleased in case you want to distinguish between a click and a drag.